# options for implementing a PowerPoint viewer on HTML for a web app (other than embedding with provided i-frame tag)

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, powerpoint, ms-wopi

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish: displaying a PowerPoint presentation on HTML. The user should be able to start and execute the presentation exactly like when you press the "Start Presentation" button in Microsoft PowerPoint: it goes fullscreen, transitions and animations are played, it goes to the next slide if a duration for the slide is set, on click it goes to the next slide, arrow keys are used for navigating slides and so on. **Only need to run the presentation, NOT editing.**

I've been looking around and came up with these three approaches:

1. Creating the viewer from scratch and processing/reading the .pptx file using HTML, CSS and JS, **btw is this is feasible?** 
   I know it won't be easy, but it seems it would take a lot of time to develop (I'm just one person working in the project).
   Also free or paid approaches both are fine, the more options I get to know the better.
2. WOPI host, the problem with this is I need a paid Office365 membership.
3. Embedding using a third party such as Office Online, Google Docs, slides.com, the problem I noticed is that the i-frame they provide lacks from functionality and customization.

So my question is, are there other approaches for this? or is this all there is?

**Final Edit**: I decided to go with [iSpring Converter Pro](https://www.ispringsolutions.com/ispring-converter). Seems like the best option overall

Comment: yes, another approach is you can convert your PPTX to mp4 which can be used in a html5 video tag.

Answer (score 2):

1. Insane amount of work -> not worth it. But you could use a paid library such as [`Aspose.Slides`](https://products.aspose.app/slides/viewer)
2. MS WOPI is, indeed, a way to do that. WOPI clients such as Office Online and Office Online Server offer an action called [`present`](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/discovery.html#action-present). That's what you're looking for.
3. What about [SlideShare's API](https://www.slideshare.net/developers/oembed) and [oEmbed](https://oembed.com/)?

Another approach:

4. Convert the PPTX to ODF and use https://viewerjs.org/